# How to reuse Fragments within a Nav Graph in a multi-module architecture?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

**Context**

I have a multi-module architecture, with multiple feature modules, it kinda looks like this:

[image]

I have multiple feature modules that depend on a `:core_library` library module that contains all the common dependencies (Retrofit, Room, etc.) and then different feature modules for each of the different app flows. Finally, the `:app` application module ties everything together.

If you want to navigate between Activities in feature modules that don't know anything about each other I use an `AppNavigator` interface:

```
interface AppNavigator {
   fun provideActivityFromFeatureModuleA(context: Context): Intent
}
```

Then in the `:app` module `Application` class I implement this interface, and since the `:app` module ties everything together it knows each of the activities within each of the feature modules:

```
class MyApp : Application(), AppNavigator {
...
   override fun provideActivityFromFeatureModuleA(context: Context): Intent {
      return Intent(context, ActivityFromA::class.java)
   }
...
}
```

This `AppNavigator` component lives in a Dagger module up in `:core_library` and it can be injected in any feature module.

I have this `:feature_login` feature module that is for when the user creates a new account and has to go through the onboarding flow, things like inviting friends to join the app, checking for `POST_NOTIFICATION` permissions, adding any more details to its account, etc.

Each of the `:feature_modules` has one `Activity` and many `Fragments` I have a navigation graph to navigate between fragments.

**The problem**

The `:feature_login` navigation graph kinda looks like this:

[image]

The thing is that I need to reuse many of these Fragments across different parts of the App, more specifically, these Fragments

[image]

For example; When I open the app and land on the main screen, I check for `POST_NOTIFICATION` permissions, and if these haven't been granted, I want to prompt the `PostNotificationFragment` that checks for that and presents the user with a UI. The `SelectSquadronFragment` + `SelectNumberFragment` should be prompted if the user wants to change them from the Settings screen. When doing something I want to prompt the user with the `InviteFriendsFragment`.

*The problem is that I don't know how to reuse these Fragments independently without having them navigate through the rest of the flow*

**What I have tried so far**

- Subgraphs don't really fix the issue. I can use the `AppNavigator` to either provide the hosting Activity I have in `:feature_login` or each individual Fragment, but the issue is still there. If the user opens `SelectSquadronFragment` + `SelectNumberFragment` from Settings, I don't want the user to have to go through `FinishFragment` afterward.
- Extracting the navigation through an interface up to the Activity. Each Fragment in that navigation graph navigates through `NavDirections`. When I want to navigate from `MedictFragment` to `InviteFriendsFragment` I use `MedicFragmentDirections`. I was thinking about having the `Activity` provide these `NavDirections`, that way I could create customized Activities with the navigation routes that I want, but honestly, I would prefer to go with something that isn't that rocket science.

Please let me know if you need me to give you more info. Any feedback is welcome.

**Example**

Let me give you a precise example of what I'm struggling with here. Let's use something simple. Let's take the `ChooseRoleFragment` as an example.

This `ChooseRoleFragment` is a simple UI that shows three buttons with three roles ("Police", "Medic", and "Fireman") during the ***login flow***, when the user clicks on one of these three buttons, he is taken to either the `PoliceFragment`, `FiremanFragment` or `MedicFragment`. This is in the ***login flow***.

Now, I need to re-use this `ChooseRoleFragment` in the "Settings" section of the app. The only difference is that when I use it there, I don't want it to navigate to the `FiremanFragment`, `MedicFragment` or `PoliceFragment`, I just want it to go back to the "Settings" screen. The "Settings" screen is on a completely different feature module that doesn't know anything about `:feature_login`

To be more clear, the `ChooseRoleFragment` navigate to either the `PoliceFragment`, the `FiremanFragment` or the `MedicFragment` through a navigation graph. That means that in the `ChooseRoleFragment` once I click on each of the options I have something like this:

```
    class ChooseRoleFragment : Fragment() {
        //...
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            bindings.policeBtn.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(ChooseRoleFragmentDirections.actionChooseRoleFragmentToPoliceFragment())
            }
            bindings.medicBtn.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(ChooseRoleFragmentDirections.actionChooseRoleFragmentToMedicFragment())
            }
            bindings.firemanBtn.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(ChooseRoleFragmentDirections.actionChooseRoleFragmentToFiremanFragment())
            }
        }
    }
```

So, this works perfectly for the login flow, but it won't do what I want for the "Settings" screen. So what I'm trying to figure out is, should I extract those `NavDirections` somewhere? That way when I want to re-use this Fragment in the "Settings" screen I can just override the `NavDirections` and have it navigate somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to pass different interface implementation into the ViewModel's constructor, so that when accessed by the Fragment, it changes the destination of where you are going. You also want to extract these calls `findNavController().navigate(ChooseRoleFragmentDirections.actionChooseRoleFragmentToPoliceFragment())` to come from outside, rather than directly hardcode what the actions must do. Also, if these fragments are re-used, they can't have their own actions, the actions must come from their enclosing NavGraph.

So how do you get a different interface implementation into your Fragment or ViewModel depending on current application state?

Good question, because neither ViewModel (it hardcodes `<T extends ViewModel>` as expected type) nor Hilt (global configuration) was meant for this. I can envision two options if you're stuck with Jetpack Navigation (which you are, as your app is big):

1.) define an interface in the Fragment that is "ActionHandler", and expect FQN of an `ActionHandler` implementation as a fragment argument. Then, use `Class.forName(FQN).newInstance()` to get a reference to it, and that will define the navigation actions the Fragment must do.

2.a) define an interface in the ViewModel that is "ActionHandler", and expect `ActionHandler` as a constructor argument. Pass in a different `ActionHandler` implementation from a custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory` (probably `initializerViewModel {`) depending on the current available NavGraph. This however requires seeing the NavController in your custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory`.

2.b) combine the two ideas. An `initializerViewModel {` receives the `CreationExtras` including the associated `SavedStateHandle`, therefore you can receive a "mode"-like enum (or FQN like before) into the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` through the `SavedStateHandle`, and setup the condition for the `ActionHandler` implementation based on a fragment argument.

This way, you can create a factory for your `ActionHandler` and not have to hard-code the action handling within your Fragment class. If you use FQN, make sure to `@Keep` the class with the `@Keep` annotation, or relevant Proguard rules. This `ActionHandler` implementation needs to see multiple NavGraphs, so it'll basically be some kind of `Navigator` defined in `:app`, or at least a module that can see multiple NavGraphs.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! Q, couldn't I extract the `findNavController().navigate...` calls up to the hosting Activity. Let's say I need to launch the `ChooseRoleFragment ` from the "Settings" screen, then I'd launch an intent to the hosting Activity, pass some sort of configuration through the Intent bundle and use that to figure out which of the `Fragment` navigations should omit or not. Sounds correct?

Comment: A piece of info that I think I left out is that many of the other feature modules in the app aren't still using this one-Activity-many-Fragments kind of navigation, they just have one Activity per screen, so it's not like I can rely on every other feature module having a navigation graph.

Comment: I mean, I like the idea of extracting the navigation to the ViewModel, but I'm also trying to figure out the easiest and most digestible solution

Comment: Also, I'm thinking, maybe, could I go with `ChooseRoleFragment` being `open` extract-method the `findNavController().navigate...` calls into functions, then create a new `StandaAloneChooseRoleFragment` that overrides those two functions so it does something else?